# \begin{spacing}{X}; X = \usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

Tags: spacing, setspace

My table of contents extends over 2 pages and a 3rd with an entry. The methods suggested in the forum with \enlargethispage do not work for me due to the structure of my document. I would like to slightly modify the line spacing in the table of contents. Unfortunately, I could not find out what value X assumes for font size 12.

Many thanks for the help

```
%loading set space in the beginning of my main file
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

%what I want to do
%Y is a percentage of X yet to be determined.
\begin{spacing}{Y}
\tableofcontents
\end{spacing}
```

Comment: does it matter what the original value is, just use 0.9  or however small you can make it so it fits on the page without looking too cramped

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Trial and error also works. I tried to solve the problem this way because I hoped to understand how the setspace environment calculates and thus be able to reliably find a solution for similar problems in the future. X seems to be between 1.2357 and 1.2640.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value can be read in `setspace.sty` and it's 1.241.

But you don't need it.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

\begin{document}

\ExpandArgs{ne}\begin{spacing}{\fpeval{0.9*\baselinestretch}}
\tableofcontents
\end{spacing}

\chapter{Something}

\chapter{Something else}

\end{document}
```

Modify `0.9` to suit your needs.

Comment: Thank you very much!